# Why thread with lower priority get longer CPU time than thread with higher priority in this code

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

I'm reading Threads from `Java The complete Reference - Herbert Schildt (TATA McGRAW HILL)`. And in this example form book, Thread with lower priority should give lower value of `clicks` than Thread with higher priority. But what i got

```
low-priority thread 3000255895
hi-priority thread  2857361716
```

according to book it is something like this (difference)

```
low-priority thread 4408112
hi-priority thread  589626904
```

code

```
class Clicker implements Runnable {
    long click = 0;
    Thread t;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public Clicker (int p) {
        t  = new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(p);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            click++;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void start() {
        t.start();
    }
}

class Priority {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        Clicker hi = new Clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 2);
        Clicker lo = new Clicker(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2); 
        hi.start();
        lo.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
        }

        lo.stop();
        hi.stop();

        try {
            hi.t.join();
            lo.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("interrupted exception catched in main");
        }

        System.out.println("low-priority thread " + lo.click);
        System.out.println("hi-priority thread " + hi.click);
    }
}
```

I'm on `Intel® Core™ i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4 with Ubuntu 13.04`

with `Thread.sleep(50000);`

```
low-priority thread 14849893875
hi-priority thread 14224080358
```

Is it not a big difference

I also try with priority HI = 10 and LOw = 1, But result nearly same.

UPDATE: 
After running with 100 threads 50 with `priority = 1` and `50 with priority = 10` result is

here `time = clicks values`

```
high = 82 time = 110117529
low =  83 time = 102549208
high = 84 time = 110905795
low =  85 time = 99100530
high = 86 time = 105012756
low =  87 time = 110195297
high = 88 time = 102820088
low =  89 time = 97814606
high = 90 time = 99990839
low =  91 time = 102326356
high = 92 time = 98656119
low =  93 time = 98127243
high = 94 time = 97097823
low =  95 time = 103604394
high = 96 time = 93632744
low =  97 time = 99032550
high = 98 time = 103879116
low =  99 time = 97179029
```

With 1000 Threads `Take 4-5 min. to complete, all 4 cores at 100%`

```
low =  977 time = 23593983
high = 978 time = 23998970
low =  979 time = 23879458
high = 980 time = 22775297
low =  981 time = 21297504
high = 982 time = 22464600
low =  983 time = 20301501
high = 984 time = 19073992
low =  985 time = 19450707
high = 986 time = 19317769
low =  987 time = 18454648
high = 988 time = 17901939
low =  989 time = 16976661
high = 990 time = 17360728
low =  991 time = 16813824
high = 992 time = 15531501
low =  993 time = 14659965
high = 994 time = 12833364
low =  995 time = 13708670
high = 996 time = 13348568
low =  997 time = 12947993
high = 998 time = 12749436
low =  999 time = 9804643
```

Unpredictable output for each thread.

Comment: Try with `hi = 1` and `low = 10`. Meaning of high and low may vary depending upon the machine

Comment: same result `low-priority thread 2980140455`
 `hi-priority thread 2847417302`

Comment: So you have two threads and four cores, and you wonder why both threads are able to execute the same amount of work?

Comment: I'm not, book say that you will get difference. But here output is opposite. I'm just clearing

Comment: In all probability, **click** is not going to contain the exact number of invocations. This should have been an AtomicLong.

So how large do you want the difference to be ? +-2 isn't a big difference either.

Run one thread with MIN_PRIORITY and other thread with MAX_PRIORITY. Calculate the difference. Repeat the above experiment with 10, 100, 1000 threads. 50% of them with MIN_PRIORITY and other 50% with MAX_PRIORITY. Your results if you post will be surely enlightening.

Comment: There is next-to-no difference.  Like @parsifal says, you have enough cores to do all your work flat-out, so no significant difference.  Make 8 hi and 8 lo - see what happens then!

Comment: You need a new book :)

Comment: @MartinJames aany other book you prefer ( i am newbie, it is first time  with java)

Comment: @FF Can you put your comment in answer so i can mark it as Answer.

Comment: @FF  my update with 100 and 1000 threads

Comment: @parsifal here is update with 100% cpu load and 1000 threads but almost same result.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the example figures will be somewhat dependent upon both your platform and the author's (does the example run upon a single core?). The JVM thread prioritisation is OS/platform-specific. From [this interesting document](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml)

> Linux priorities
>
> Under Linux, you have to go through more hoops to get thread
>   priorities to function at all, although in the end, they may be more
>   useful than under Windows. In Linux:
>
> - thread priorities only work as of Java 6 onwards;
> - for them to work, you must be running as root (or with root privileges via setuid);
> - the JVM parameter -XX:UseThreadPriorities must be included

So check your Java version, your Java invocation and your privileges. I suspect (!) you only satisfy one of those criteria (your Java/JVM version).

Comment: this is the output `java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Can you add some more to get it work. I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: It looks like you need to run as root, and run your Java invocation using java -XX:UseThreadPriorities MyClass

Comment: I can run it as root but how to put -XX:UseThreadPriorities. I give command like `Java -cp ./bin Priority`. what to do?

Comment: How about `java -XX... -cp ./bin/priority.jar Priority`

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Thread priorities being a gray area under most implementations and platforms, other things you could look into are :

1. In all probability, click is not going to contain the exact number of invocations. This should have been an AtomicLong. So how large do you want the difference to be ? +-2 isn't a big difference either.
2. Run one thread with MIN_PRIORITY and other thread with MAX_PRIORITY. Calculate the difference. Repeat the above experiment with 10, 100, 1000 threads. 50% of them with MIN_PRIORITY and other 50% with MAX_PRIORITY. Your results if you post will be surely enlightening

**Edit**
Interesting, let me submit my sample program. I am under OpenJDK6 and the thread priorities :MIN_PRIORITY and MAX_PRIORITY doesn't seem to matter much. The number of clicks with the high level thread is slightly more than the number of clicks with low priority thread.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;


class Clicker implements Runnable {
    AtomicLong click = new AtomicLong();
    Thread t;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public Clicker (int p) {
        t  = new Thread(this);
        t.setPriority(p);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            click.incrementAndGet();
            longOP();
        }
    }

    private void longOP() {
        outer:
        for (int i = 2; i <= 10000 && running; i++) {
            final int NUM = i;
            for (int j = 2; j * j <= NUM && running; j++) {
                if (NUM % j == 0) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("[" + NUM + "],");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = -90; i <= 90 && running; i++) {
            double rad = Math.toRadians(i);
            double value = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(Math.PI * Math.sin(rad), 10.0))) + Math.tan(rad) * Math.cos(rad); //lol
            System.out.print("[" + i + " " + value + "],");
        }

    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void start() {
        t.start();
    }
}

public class Priority {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

        final int MAX_THREADS = 1000;
        final long MAX_RUN_TIME = 60 * 1000; //millis

        Clicker clickHi[] = new Clicker[MAX_THREADS];
        Clicker clickLow[] = new Clicker[MAX_THREADS];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; ++i) {
            clickHi[i] = new Clicker(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
            clickLow[i] = new Clicker(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 

            clickHi[i].start();
            clickLow[i].start();
        }


        try {
            Thread.sleep(MAX_RUN_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            System.out.println("main thread interrupted");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; ++i) {
            clickHi[i].stop();
            clickLow[i].stop();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; ++i) {
            try {
                clickHi[i].t.join();
                clickLow[i].t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                System.out.println("interrupted exception catched in main");
            }
        }

        long totalLowClicks = 0, totalHighClicks = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; ++i) {
            totalLowClicks += clickLow[i].click.longValue();
            totalHighClicks += clickHi[i].click.longValue();

            System.out.println("low-priority thread " + clickLow[i].click);
            System.out.println("hi-priority thread " + clickHi[i].click);
        }

        System.out.println("Sum of LOW clicks : " + totalLowClicks);
        System.out.println("Sum of HI  clicks : " + totalHighClicks);
    }
}
```

The above program is cpu intensive. You may encounter Out Of Memory Errors. But just for fun, post your result.